# A misleading commutative diagram

Tags: notation, category-theory

Let $U$ be a set, let $\phi$ be an involutive bijection of $U$ with itself.

Let $A$, $B$ be subsets of $U$.

Consider the commutative diagram $A \overset{\phi}{\leftrightarrow} B$ describing a bijection between $A$ and $B$ (that is $\phi$ restricted to $A\times B$).

This diagram is misleading into thinking that $\phi: A\rightarrow B$ is a self-inverse morphism (that is $\phi\circ\phi=1$), what cannot be true (and even is undefined) if $A\ne B$.

Please advise on how to make a less misleading diagram on this topic.

Comment: I think that to suggest that $\phi$ was self-inverse, you would need two arrows, one in each direction, each labeled with $\phi$.

Comment: $$A\overset{\phi}{\rightarrow} B\\\iota \updownarrow \,\,\,\,\,\,\, \updownarrow\iota \\ A\underset{\phi^{-1}}{\leftarrow} B$$

Comment: @DavidP: That's not what's being discussed; your diagram holds true for any isomorphism $\phi$. If I understand the question, porton wants to know if the diagram $A \overset{\phi}{\leftrightarrow} B$ will confuse people into thinking that $\phi^2 = \text{id}_A$, which is not necessarily the case.  My suggestion was that that diagram would _not_ confuse people that way, and that if he wanted people to think that $\phi^2=\text{id}_A$ (which he does not) he would need to show arrows in both directions.

Comment: @MJD I assumed this is a question posed by a teacher or a text, and that the idea behind it is that a reader might see $\phi$ as the same map from $A$ to $B$ and from $B$ to $A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think people will not be confused by

$$\require{AMScd}
A\stackrel\phi\leftrightarrow B
$$

and that to make people think that $\phi^2 = 1$ you would need something like this:

$$\begin{CD}
A @>{\phi}>>  B \\
@VV{\text{id}_A}V @VV{\text{id}_B}V  \\
A@<{\phi}<< B
\end{CD}
$$

or the analogous triangular diagram obtained by merging the two $B$s (or the two $A$s), or similarly something like this: $$A{{\stackrel\phi\rightarrow}\atop{\stackrel\leftarrow\phi}}B$$

Comment: By the definition of commutative diagram, wouldn't you need at least a triangle to imply that $\phi$ is a self-inverse? I don't see how the bottom diagram implies this.

Comment: When I learned the notation from Freyd, he said that _every_ pair of paths between the same two objects should be deemed to commute unless there is a specific notation to the contrary.  For example, in http://i.stack.imgur.com/jS4mu.png (from Fryed and Ščedrov's _Categories, Allegories_) the diagram defining an equalizer of $f:A\to B$ and $g:A\to B$ must have a notation (“puncture mark”) between $f$ and $g$ since otherwise they would be deemed equal.  The example above is even clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it would help to clearly indicate that the two $\phi$'s are really different functions (with different domains), like

$$A{{\stackrel{\phi|_A}\rightarrow}\atop{\stackrel\leftarrow{\phi|_B}}}B$$